# MySQL error handling for query that might not return anything

Tags: php, mysql

I have this MySQL query that has to run when the page is loaded, however not all users have the data required to return anything, this gives out a massive error.

Is there anyway i can handle this error so when the query doesn't return anything, i can just return say "0" in the function. Here is the code;

```
function getTimesUp($email) {   
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT uptime FROM info WHERE user='$email'");
    $uptime1 = mysql_result($query1, 0);

    return $uptime1;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the query to see if it returned a `0` number of rows.

```
function getTimesUp($email)
{   
  $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT uptime FROM info WHERE user='$email'");

  if(mysql_num_rows($query1) == 0)
  {
   return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    $uptime1 = mysql_result($query1, 0);
    return $uptime1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check whether `mysql_num_rows()` is greater than zero.